# Send array of file attachment or multiple file attach in sendGrid (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, multer

How do i pass an array of attachment to **sendGrid's attachment** Array.

**multer** handles the form,

HTML

```
 <div class="file-field input-field">
        <div class="btn btn-small z-depth-0">
          <span><i class="small material-icons">attach_file</i></span>
          <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" multiple />
        </div>
        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
          <input class="file-path" type="text" placeholder="Attach a file?">
        </div>
     </div>
```

Multer handles the form:

```
upload.array('fileInput')
```

i can access the files and text fields as below

```
const files = req.files;
  const { email, content, subject, cc } = req.body;
  
  let allFilePath;
  let allFileOriginalName;
  let allFileType;

  Trying to loop here...  

  let res1 = files.map((file) => file.path);
  let res2 = files.map((file) => file.originalname);
  let res3 = files.map((file) => file.mimetype);

  allFilePath = res1;
  allFileOriginalName = res2;
  allFileType = res3;

  console.log(allFilePath, allFileType, allFileOriginalName);

  const pathToAttachment = `${allFilePath}`;
  const attachments = fs.readFileSync(pathToAttachment).toString('base64');
```

Now, if i try to use it here i get error

```
        ...
        attachments: [
            {
              content: [attachments],
              filename: [allFileOriginalName],
              type: [allFileType],
              disposition: 'attachment',
            },
          ],

 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'uploads\athpyCXtW.jpg, uploads\2NkGsPy936.jpg'
```

probably it thought these two files upload are one. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be useful for someone else.

just loop through files and return values you need

```
// Loop through files to return some fields
      const attachments = files.map((file) => {
        const pathToAttachment = file.path;
        const attachment = fs.readFileSync(pathToAttachment).toString('base64');
        return {
          filename: file.originalname,
          disposition: 'attachment',
          type: file.mimetype,
          content: attachment,
        };
      });
```

Then attach to attachment array

```
....
attachments: attachments,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//files is array of image Url 
     let attachment = await Promise.all(files.map(val => imageToBase64(val)))
        attachments = attachment && attachment.map(attachment => ({
          filename: 'attachment.png',
          disposition: 'attachment',
          type:'application/image',
          content: attachment
        }));
      const body = await sgMail.send({
      to: email,
      from,
      subject: "subject ",
      html: "helloo",
      ...(
        attachments && attachments.length && {
          attachments: attachments
        }
      )
    });
    return body;
```